# BDD Goals and Properties

Tags: bdd

I am unsure about the goals of BDD after reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development.

> Which of the following are goals of Behavior-Driven Design (BDD)? Select all that apply.
>
> 1. To verify that the application meets the specification
> 2. To validate that the design does what the customer wants
> 3. To help the customer understand the use of the application
> 4. To ask questions about the behavior of an application before and during development

I selected (1), (2), (3), and (4) on the quiz since all seemed to be goals of BDD, but I got the question wrong. Which of these are not goals of BDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of BDD is "software that matters". That's been the tag line since Dan North started talking about it back in 2004. It's one of the reasons why it's changed a little bit since its inception, and now includes things like Feature Injection; because every time we find a place where we can use BDD and still write software that *doesn't* matter, we fix BDD.

All four elements you've listed here are things that people commonly do as part of BDD (and yes, I've seen people use it to help the customer understand what they *really* want and how to use something a bit differently), with the aim of writing software that matters, though IMO if you're using BDD to verify or validate something, you're probably already too late.

Comment: Thank you! Why would it be to late to use BDD to verify or validate something?

Comment: Because by then you've already written the software, and maybe it won't matter. BDD works best as a problem-exploration tool (analysis) rather than a solution-validating one (testing - the tests are a nice by-product).

Comment: Also just updated the Wikipedia page to include the goal. Thanks for that prompt!

Answer (score 3):

Helping the customer understand the use of the application is not one of the goals of BDD.

Comment: Thanks! Would you explain why it is not a goal of BDD?

Comment: In all honesty I took the quiz too and that one was false.  The key word is "goal".  BDD **can** be used to help the customer understand the application but (AS IT PERTAINS TO THE CLASS YOU ARE TAKING) it is not a goal.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how helping the customer understand the application's use is not a goal pertaining to this class. Did you understand that that choice wasn't a goal of BDD from the lectures or from another source I've missed? I watched the lectures and looked through the lecture slides and was only able to determine that the fourth answer choice was a goal of BDD in the context of this class (it was in one of the multiple-choice questions the instructor asked during the lecture). I couldn't determine whether the other answer choices were goals from the lecture.